# Both multiprocessing.map and joblib use only 1 cpu after upgrade from Ubuntu 10.10 to 12.04

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ubuntu-12.04

I had some perfectly working python code which used multiprocessing module and loaded all 8 CPUs on my machine at 100%.

After I upgraded from Ubuntu 10.10 to 12.04 (the most evident thing, maybe I did something else that broke everything), it stopped working. After lots of debugging, I found that even in the simplest use case, both modules are only using 1 CPU:

```
from pylab import *
import multiprocessing as mp
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def f(i):
    # Slow calculation
    x = 1
    for j in range(100000): x = cos(x)
    print i, x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Try to multiprocess with multiprocessing
    mp.Pool(processes=8).map(f, range(100))
    # Try to multiprocess with joblib
    Parallel(n_jobs=8)(delayed(f)(i) for i in range(100))
```

I need to use all 8 CPUs in my system. Any ideas of what I should look at to fix the issue?

Comment: could it be due to your Python version changing? I know that the default Python version changes from 2.6 -> 2.7 when going from Ubuntu 10 -> 12

Comment: You might be able to fix this problem using `taskset` -  see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639779/python-what-determines-whether-different-processes-are-assigned-to-the-same-or?lq=1)

Comment: Which value does `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` return? If it is not 8, there is a problem.

Comment: FWIW, on my 12.10 running python 2.7.3, the `mp.Pool().map()` call consumes 100% of all 4 cpus in my system.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on 13.04.

Comment: If you have solved the problem then you really ought to write it as an answer and mark it as solved. This helps de-clutter the place and also helps the search engines.

Comment: I tried the same procedure for a Jupyter notebook, and it does not work. In placed that `os` command as my first cell before I import any libraries. Any ideas on how to get this to work on Jupyter notebooks?

Comment: @user1084871 Please post your answer as an answer

Answer (score 0):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@user1084871](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084871/user1084871)'s question post.

> As [@ali_m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1461210/ali-m) pointed out in a comment here and in the answer to
> [Why does multiprocessing use only a single core after I import numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639779/what-determines-whether-different-python-processes-are-assigned-to-the-same-or-d) the problem is related to `numpy` messing up with cpu affinity. Calling
>
> ```
> os.system('taskset -p 0xffffffff %d' % os.getpid())
> ```
>
> before I do any multiprocessing solved the problem for me.